# Finding Random Time between given range using Randbetween function in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I wish to find a Random Time between a given Time range containing Time format HH MM SS using a Randbetween function from excel. I just google around and came to know below function helps to get the result i need. but i need an explanation as i dint understand how this formula works. eg i dont know why it use 0 here and multiply and divide by 1000

> =(RANDBETWEEN(0,($B$14-$A$14)*10000)/10000)+$A$14

```
B14 is ending time   eg: 8:30
A14 is starting time eg: 7:30
```

Comment: RANDBETWEEN calculates a random whole number between two numbers.  Due to the nature of your request, the 10000's are there to allow it to calculate second values due to how Excel stores Time values (whole numbers are days, fractions are hours, minutes, and seconds).  For an alternate, you can use the `RAND()` function which generates a random number between 0 and less than 1: `=RAND()*(B14-A14)+A14`

Comment: sorry its time format . Just update as 8:30 and 7:30

Comment: The 10000 is arbitrary it allows the use of numbers that have 5 decimal places.  With minutes this is enough, in fact `1440` would do it.  If seconds are involved it is not enough, use `86400`

Comment: 1 day = 24 hours.  Therefore 1/24 would give you the hours,  1 hour = 60 minutes, therefore 1/(24*60) would give you hours and minutes.  1 minute = 60 seconds, therefore 1(/24*60*60)  would give you the accuracy of HH:MM:SS.  OR as Scott Craner pointed out 86400 = 24*60*60.

Comment: may i ask why 0 is used in the formula

Comment: The formula is finding out how much time there is between start and finish.  it then finds a random amount of time greater than or equal to 0 and less then or equal to the amount of time between start and end.  When this random number has been determined, it adds it to the starting time.

Comment: @bbmac look at what you are doing with the result you are adding a number between 0 and the difference of the two to the lower one.  so for a truly random there needs to be a chance that the lower time will be returned, so 0 + any number is that number.

Comment: @ScottCraner . so does that mean 100000 is theoretically wrong and i should mention 86400 if i need till second to be displayed in random number

Comment: Yes, otherwise you will be skipping some seconds as it does not have the precision needed for seconds.

Comment: But the formula @tigeravatar gave will do seconds and parts of a second as it goes out to 15 significant digits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say we have two genuine times like:

9:15:23 AM
and
2:34:21 PM

If we first convert both times into **integer seconds**, we can use `RANDBETWEEN()`.  Place the values in **A1** and **A2**

then in **B1** enter:

```
=A1*24*60*60
```

and copy downward.

In **C1** enter:

=randbetween(b1,b2)/86400

and format as time:

[image]

Comment: does that mean 100000 seems to be theoretically  wrong and instead i should add 86400 second .